# Parsing URLs with HTMLParser

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to parse the HTML of a URL using HTMLParser? I've got the basic parser setup using it to parse HTML written inside the .feed function

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class myParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print "Encountered some data  :", data

parser = myParser()
parser.feed('')
```

I was wondering if it would be possible for me to do this with a website so it parses all of the markup of whichever website I ask it to. Is this possible with HTMLParser or would I have to use something like BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup best ... It would help you dissolve everything concerning HTML, Used it recently to build a web crawler worked perfectly!